# DAC70508 connected to Arduino does not give any output

Tags: arduino, dac

I am trying to use a [DAC70508](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac70508.pdf?ts=1648472049590&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FDAC70508) with an Arduino Mega, but I do not get any output from the DAC.

I connected the SPI communication pins and the power supply pins of the DAC to the Arduino (Vio and Vdd to 5V), and I did not connect the REF pin of the DAC because I want to use the internal reference.

The Arduino code is :

```
#include<SPI.h>

int CS = 32;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(CS, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);
  SPI.begin();
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE1);
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV128);
}

char byte1 = 0b00000110;
char byte2 = 0b10101010;
char byte3 = 0b01010101;

void loop() {    
  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);

  digitalWrite(CS, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(5);

  SPI.transfer(byte1);
  SPI.transfer(byte2);
  SPI.transfer(byte3);

  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);

  delay(70);
}
```

And finally, I have the following graphs (2V/div vertically, 40 µS/div horizontally) :

[image]

Yellow is MOSI, Red is Clock, Green is Chip select. I am trying to send the frame 0x08 0xAA 0x55 (the actual data is not important, I just want to get an output). All the default config registers should be enough to at least output a voltage if I am not mistaken.

One of my hypothesis is that the Arduino outputs its data by block of 8 bits while the DAC is waiting for one block of 24 bits, but I am not sure it really is an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have tested the obvious first : the component was just badly soldered, which means some pins were not connected.

At least you know this code works if you are interested in doing the same thing.

Comment: The malformed scope traces did indicate that chip ground pin might have been unconnected.